# image display from a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, html-select

I'm a newbie in a programming and I'm trying to create a drop down menu of list of countries (from a text file countries.txt) and when you select a country it will display a country's flag. Anyone had any idea? I thought I can use a get/post request from flask but right now I have it as a text box... I can't use jQuery to create a database which is what most tutorials are using...

Edit: It can't be hardcoded into 50 lines of select "country name" -> "country image"... I thought I can use a for loop but not sure how to...

```
@bp.route("/", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def form():
    if request.method == "POST":
        image = os.path.join("/", "static", "img", f"{request.form['image']}.png")
        error = None
        if not image:
            error = "image is required."
        if error is None:
            return render_template("image.html", image=image)
        flash(error)
    return render_template("form.html")



 <h1>Select a state</h1>
    <form method="post">
    <input name="image" id="image" required><br>
    <br></vr><input type="submit" button class="button button1"; value="Show the flag">
  </select></form>
```

Comment: You should be able to code it directly in javascript and HTML with no support from Flask. If you need to use Flask, try using Jinja templating to write it into the HTML that is sent from the server. Also, I'd like to see how jQuery is used to create databases

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to without just hardcoding it... anyone has any ideas?

Comment: username checks out... But as I said, check out the [jinja documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#filters) (Flask uses Jinja). It is *not* hardcoding.

Comment: I think it's way the documentation you provided is way too high level for me to understand...